# redirect old site with query to new domain with query

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm looking for an htaccess rule to 301 redirect an old domain search result page, to a new domains result page keeping only the "query" parameter.

For example: change from `http://myoldwebsite.com/search?query=free+templates&type=post&submit=` to `http://mynewwebsite.com/?s=free+templates`.

I've found a method of redirecting each url manually, but I'm thinking there is an easier way to accomplish this using a single rule.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?myoldwebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)query=([^&]*)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/?$ http://mynewwebsite.com/?s=%1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Beautifull code! Thanks so much anubhava! This is exactly what I needed. I dropped the first RewriteCond, and this worked perfect (just had to get ahold of that query parameter so i could use it lol).